# add functionality to instance of System.Collections.Generic.List(of T).Remove

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics

I have a class with an instance of System.Collections.Generic.List(of T) that is exposed as public property.

```
Public ReadOnly Property ActiveDisplaysList() As List(Of DisplayProcess)
    Get
        Return mActiveDisplaysList
    End Get
End Property
```

I call into the class and remove items as needed via:

```
<class instance name>.ActiveDisplaysList.Remove(itemToRemove)
```

This is all working as expected, but I need to invoke additional code when an item is removed from the instance of the list.  It doesn't look like there is an event that fires when an item is removed, and creating an entire derived class just to handle this feels like overkill.

Any suggestions?

Comment: no need for another class - just add it to the class which implements `ActiveDisplaysList`...`myFoo.RemoveAndDoSomething(itemToRemove)`

Comment: ... or use a BindingList, which does have events.